# How to Control Sequence of Bean Creating and Component Scanning In Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, javabeans, autowired

**Updated**

I am Beginner to Spring and I tried to implement spring security application using Java Based Configuration. But now I have to  Control sequence of bean creating and component scanning of application.

This is my configuration class

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public void configureAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(this.userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public Md5PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new Md5PasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.headers().cacheControl();
        http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/authProxy").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/login").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .addFilterBefore(new JWTLoginFilter(authenticationManager()), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .addFilterBefore(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
}
```

and here is the `JWTLoginFilter`

```
public class JWTLoginFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

    private TokenAuthenticationService tokenAuthenticationService;

    public JWTLoginFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        super(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/login"));
        setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
        tokenAuthenticationService = new TokenAuthenticationService();
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse)
            throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {

        AccountCredentials credentials = new ObjectMapper().readValue(httpServletRequest.getInputStream(), AccountCredentials.class);

        final Authentication authentication = getAuthenticationManager()
                .authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(credentials.getUsername(),
                        credentials.getPassword()));
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(credentials.getUsername(), credentials.getPassword());
        return getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(token);
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain, Authentication authentication)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        String name = authentication.getName();
        tokenAuthenticationService.addAuthentication(response, name);
    }
}
```

This is working fine. 
But all thing going wrong When I try to declare `JWTLoginFilter` as service with `@Service` annotation and while I am trying to Autowire that.

The Changes that I did as Follows.

this is configuration class.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public void configureAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(this.userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public Md5PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new Md5PasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Autowired
    JWTLoginFilter jwtLoginFilter;


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.headers().cacheControl();
        http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/authProxy").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/login").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .addFilterBefore(jwtLoginFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .addFilterBefore(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
}
```

And this is my new `JWTLoginFilter`

```
@Service
public class JWTLoginFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

    @Autowired
    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    private TokenAuthenticationService tokenAuthenticationService;

    public JWTLoginFilter() {
        super(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/login"));
        setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
        tokenAuthenticationService = new TokenAuthenticationService();
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse)
            throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {

        AccountCredentials credentials = new ObjectMapper().readValue(httpServletRequest.getInputStream(), AccountCredentials.class);

        final Authentication authentication = getAuthenticationManager()
                .authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(credentials.getUsername(),
                        credentials.getPassword()));
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(credentials.getUsername(), credentials.getPassword());
        return getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(token);
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain, Authentication authentication)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        String name = authentication.getName();
        tokenAuthenticationService.addAuthentication(response, name);
    }
}
```

This Code gives runtime error called

```
Error starting Tomcat context. Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException. Message: Error creating bean with name 'JWTLoginFilter' defined in file [/media/dilanka/Stuff/CODEBASE/Inspection-Application/Inspection-AuthProxy/target/classes/com/shipxpress/inspection/security/jwt/JWTLoginFilter.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: authenticationManager must be specified
```

The error is as my thought at the beginning, `ComponentScan` Scanning and initiating `JWTLoginFilter`. But at that time `AuthenticationManager` bean has not created. So It is not auto wiring.

So I have to create `AuthenticationManager` bean before scanning `JWTLoginFilter`, But It is not possible because it has to create in class that extended by `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` and spring allows one `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` extended class. So I can't initiate it in another class. 
Also

```
 @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {}
```

has to declare in `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` extended class and this method use `jwtLoginFilter`. So all

```
@Autowired
    JWTLoginFilter jwtLoginFilter;
```

and

```
@Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
```

and

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.headers().cacheControl();
        http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/authProxy").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/login").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .addFilterBefore(jwtLoginFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .addFilterBefore(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
```

has to define it in `WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter class` and has to Control sequence of bean creating and component scanning of the application. Does anyone have an idea? please help me.

***updated-->***

I Tried to implement JWTLoginFilter as follows,

```
@Service
public class JWTLoginFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

    private TokenAuthenticationService tokenAuthenticationService;

    @Autowired
    public JWTLoginFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        super(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/login"));
    }
...
}
```

But it gives the following error

```
The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:

┌─────┐
|  JWTLoginFilter defined in file [/media/dilanka/Stuff/CODEBASE/Inspection-Application/DR-136812421-dbchangesSendAsMail/Inspection-Application/Inspection-AuthProxy/target/classes/com/shipxpress/inspection/security/jwt/JWTLoginFilter.class]
↑     ↓
|  webSecurityConfig (field com.shipxpress.inspection.security.jwt.JWTLoginFilter com.shipxpress.inspection.config.WebSecurityConfig.jwtLoginFilter)
└─────┘
```

I think the problem is, If we auto wire Constructor as above, Then `JWTLoginFilter` can't create without creating `Configuration` beans creating. But Configuration beans needs `JWTLoginFilter` bean. So it can't create without JWTLoginFilter bean.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@Autowired` annotation will be processed *after* constructor of bean has been called. So your exception does not depend on the sequence of bean creating. If you need to invoke `setAuthenticationManager` from constructor you can apply `@Autowired` to the constructor:

```
@Service
public class JWTLoginFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;    
    private TokenAuthenticationService tokenAuthenticationService;

    @Autowired
    public JWTLoginFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager; //if you will need this instance in future
        super(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/login"));
        setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
        tokenAuthenticationService = new TokenAuthenticationService();
    }

    ...
}
```

Then appropriate bean will be passed to the constructor automatically.

Another solution is to make all initialization in the  `@PostConstruct` method. This method will be called just after `@Autowired` annotation has been processed:

```
@Service
public class JWTLoginFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

    @Autowired
    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;    
    private TokenAuthenticationService tokenAuthenticationService;

    public JWTLoginFilter(){
        super(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/login"));
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct() {
        setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
        tokenAuthenticationService = new TokenAuthenticationService();
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: I tried your first solution. I will update the problem with that implementation. It also gives an error. If we auto wire Constructor as you said, Then JWTLoginFilter can't create without creating configuration bean creating. But configuration bean needs JWTLoginFilter bean. So it can't create without JWTLoginFilter bean. So it gives 'The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context from a cycle:' error.
Anyway, Thank you for your Answer. Do you have any suggestion to avoid this error

Answer (score 0):

- Spring Boot has multiple conditional annotations to use like @ConditionalOnBean to control the sequencing of bean creation
- Look into package org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition for all the conditionals available
- For the your example, best way is to have constructor injection of AuthenticationManager in JWTLoginFilter